# Can an MRI identify the reason why a pygmy hedgehog has a neurological problem?

Tags: veterinarian, hedgehog

I have a pygmy hedgehog which has a neurological problem with her legs. She cannot stand at all. She was running around my room on October 6th, and three days later she cannot even stand. Nothing is broken. I have visited the vet 5 times so far. She gets an antibiotic (Enrotron), dosed at 0.1ml per day, as well as some other medicines (not listed because I think they don't matter).

I would like to get an MRI performed on her to find what the reason is for her neurological problems. Is it possible at all? I just need to know if it is a good diagnostic before we diagnose her with [Wobbly Hedgehog Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wobbly_hedgehog_syndrome) (which can only be 100% diagnosed after death).

Why do I think it might not be Wobbly Hedgehog Syndrome?

- It has happened too quickly for WHS
- She has a strong ability to curl into a ball without any problems

Why do I think it might be Wobbly Hedgehog Syndrome?

- Mobility issue (and that is all) – for a few days she had difficulty walking, wobbling when standing still, and sometimes falling over

Comment: These are questions you should discuss with the vet. They can advise you best and they know your hedgehog.

Comment: I know how MRI works from my biologic studies, but I do not know, what WHS is. May you explain? If it is something physical broken in tissues, it may be visible in MRI. But if ot is something else, like chemical issue, then it would be hard to see in first level

Comment: @Allerleirauh WHS is disease called Wobbly Hedgehog Syndrome with neurological symptoms.

Comment: A not-deep search about WHS brought me the insight, that the scientists look with microscopes for the broken tissues. So I assume MRI would not bring a good quality image to spot such tiny issues I assume.

Comment: @Allerleirauh it was rather to detect wrong things in spin or tumors or sth else we cannot see much well on x-ray images.

Comment: I understand. But if you would find nothing visible, then you still can not decide if it is WHS or not...